# Have process automatically restart with upstart and initctl

Tags: upstart

I'm on CentOS 6.3.

I've written a script in Python for the purpose of an app that I'm making. I want it to run as a process that will restart itself if it fails.

I have a .conf file like so:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
script
    /usr/bin/python /home/myself/myscript.py
end script
```

I can start it with `initctl start myscript` but when it fails, it doesn't restart. If I do `initctl status myscript` it says `stop/waiting`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved this.

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
respawn
script
    exec /usr/bin/python /home/myself/myscript.py
end script
```

I added `respawn` and placed `exec` before the command. According to this: http://newcome.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/running-programs-as-linux-daemons-using-upstart/ `exec` is an Upstart specific stanza instead of the normal `exec` command.